# Как сделать скрипт для автоматического выхода из всех каналов телеграм?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

Возникла проблема в том, что нужно выйти из всех каналов на большом кол-ве аккаунтов. Попробовал порыть api, нашёл что-то похожее, но там возникает проблема в логгировании и поиска id канала

Comment: Причем здесь бот? Скорее скрипт. `UserAPI Telegram`.

Comment: Да, скрипт, просто я чаще всего его так называю. Я в api смотрел, там есть только способ, который получает все данные о канале, а мне конкретно надо ссылку